# CSS Sideways text stuck on the page's corner

Tags: css, text, rotation, transform, css-transforms

I'm having some trouble with css rotations and positioning.

I'd like to make a webpage's title sideways (rotate -90°, so it reads from left to right -> bottom to top) and sticked to the bottom right corner of the webpage.

Here's the CSS I used so far :

```css
.gallerytitle {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 90%;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    border: 1px #fff solid;
    }

.gallerytitletext {
    font: 120px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    color: #008aff;
    position:relative;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

(.gallerytitletext is a div inside .gallerytitle)

I tried to mess with the transform-origin property but I haven't been successful so far.

Is there a better way to achieve this ? It's a real PITA to do this with transform-origin. I've tried like a hundred different configurations and I can't set the text to the right spot.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to achieve something similar - the DIV must be absolutely positioned. It's the only way to achieve this without bothering with the transform-origin stuff !